# iproute2 tunnel sit

Tags: ipv6, linux-networking, tunneling

According to this article
http://www.consulintel.euro6ix.org/ietf/draft-palet-v6ops-6in4-vs-6over4-01.html
6in4 is only encapsulation mechanism that is used by transition mechanisms like 6over4.
What kind of tunnel is
 
ip tunnel mode sit ?

I found on many sites that it is 6in4 or 6over4. 6in4 is incorrect according to this article. 6over4 uses only 
multicast addresses but this command allows use other ip addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Tunnel mode "site" is a 6in4 connection.  This is how I would describe them

6in4 - a manually configured IPv6 tunnel that operated over IPv4.

6to4 - an automatically configured tunnel (uses 6in4 underneath with a bit of control magic)

Teredo - an automatically configured tunnel (uses UDP underneath)

6over4 - an automatically configured tunnel (uses IPv4 Multicasting, not widely supported).